# Parsing file like .ini using bash, sed, awk

Tags: bash, parsing, sed, awk

I have a file like this:

```
[User1]  <- unique id
name=    <- values can be empty
pwd=
...
         <- empty line
[User2]
name=
pwd=
..

[User3]
name=
pwd=
..
```

I need ability: 
to get the fields values for `User2` 
to change the field falue (e.g. `pwd`).

PS Using **bash**, **sed** or **awk** is preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with three rules like this (nawk compatible):

```
awk -F= '
  /^\[/ { user=$1; gsub("[][]","",user) }
  user == "User2" && $1 == "pwd" { $0=$1"=some_pwd" }
  1
'
```

Output:

```
[User1]
name=
pwd=
...

[User2]
name=
pwd=some_pwd
..

[User3]
name=
pwd=
..
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution to change the value of pwd.  This will add an extra newline to the end of the record if `pwd` is the last field.

```
awk '/^\[User2\]/ { sub( "\npwd=[^\n]*(\n|$)", 
    "\npwd=newvalue\n") } 1' ORS='\n\n' RS= input-file > output-file
mv output-file > input-file
```

Comment: Actually I don't know the last field. Also, count of fields can varry from different `Users`

Comment: Field count is irrelevant, but if the field you are changing happens to be the last one, you will get an extra newline.  If the extra newline matters, it can easily be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This one is a clear win for Python vs. AWK, as Python comes with a built-in module for just this sort of problem.

The module's name changed from Python 2.x to Python 3.x; the `try` block at the top should allow this to work with either Python 2.x or Python 3.x (and I tested it with both on my computer).

EDIT: I just slightly improved the answer.  Now instead of writing a new file, it writes a temp file, and when it is successfully done it deletes the original file and renames the temp file to the original file name.  On non-Windows system the step of removing the original file is optional.

```
import os
import sys

try:
    import ConfigParser as cp
except ImportError:
    import configparser as cp

try:
    _, fname = sys.argv
except Exception:
    print("Usage: configedit <filename>")

temp_file = fname + ".tempfile"

c = cp.ConfigParser()
c.read(fname)

c.set("User2", "pwd", "XkcdApprovedLongerPassword")
with open(temp_file, "w") as f:
    c.write(f)

os.remove(fname)
os.rename(temp_file, fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

As requested via sed:

```
sed -i "/\[User2\]/,/^$/{s/\(^pwd\)\=.*$/\1\=password/}"
```

Change "password" in the line above to whatever you want to change the password to within the file.

This script will search between "[User2]" and the next blank line.
It will then find the line starting with "pwd=" and change anything after that.

For those looking closely I didn't capture the "=" sign for readability for the requester.